# Ant-alias font, certain characters don't appear

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

So, I have attempted to anti-alias text in AS3 with the following:

```
timeText = new TextField();
timeText.text = gameTime.toString();
interfaceLayer.addChild(timeText);
timeText.x = 545;
timeText.y = 0;
timeText.selectable = false;
timeText.embedFonts = true;
timeText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
```

I am using the Arial Rounded MT Bold font. My problem is that the font is anti-aliased fine, but when the timer counts down from 30 the numbers 8 to 4 aren't showing up, so instead of the timer showing `28` or `18` for example, it just shows `2` and `1` with a blank space after it. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. How did you embed the font? 2. You seem to mean that if you change the value of antiAliasType the characters will show, right?

Comment: Try increasing the width of your TextField and check if it's displaying properly.

Comment: Make sure all the numbers are embedded, and that the textField is wide enough. That will surely solve your problem.

Comment: I went into the library, clicked the little drop down box and selected `New Font..`. I chose the font and give it an instance name and whatnot. Letters all work fine and the numbers 1, 2, 3, 9 and 0 all show fine, it's just 4-8 that doesn't. I increased the width of the text field and this still happened.

Comment: have you tried a different font?